How to join the Ubuntu 22.04 Server to the Window Active Directory
I have new server running on the ubuntu and I want to join that server to our existing AD which is resolve as "ad.xyz.edu" and under that AD our department (OU) "med.abc.edu" is resides , Now I want to add the med.abc.edu users to the new server. our username is like john.doe@xyz.edu which is using the main domain name
When users attempt to use Kerberos and specify a principal or user name   
  without specifying what administrative Kerberos realm that principal      
  belongs to, the system appends the default realm.  The default realm may  
  also be used as the realm of a Kerberos service running on the local      
  machine.  Often, the default realm is the uppercase version of the local  
  DNS domain.                                                               
                                                                            
  Default Kerberos version 5 realm: 


Enter the hostnames of Kerberos servers in the FD3S.SRV.WORLD Kerberos 
 realm separated by spaces.                                                
                                                                            
  Kerberos servers for your realm: 

 Enter the hostname of the administrative (password changing) server for   
  the FD3S.SRV.WORLD Kerberos realm.                                     
                                                                            
  Administrative server for your Kerberos realm:

What should I need to enter to join the AD "ad.xyz.edu" or "med.abc.edu" As far as i can tell i don't think we have to use the med.abc.edu
Note ::When I ran the "realm join -U username@xyz.edu "ad.xyz.edu" ask for the password as I am not admin at the ad.xyz.edu level but I am admin at med.abc.edu level so is that some what I have to ask to the AD admin or is there any other method to work around


When users attempt to use Kerberos

Your configuration prompts are for "raw" Kerberos authentication; you can use this for AD (partially) but it will not give you a fully functional join – it won't be able to retrieve user information and it won't securely verify passwords; it's practically only for outbound usage to AD-joined machines.

The Kerberos realm is the upper-case version of the AD domain name, likely AD.XYZ.EDU. This is always the same for all users in the domain, and has no relationship to your custom "UPN suffix" in AD.
The "Kerberos servers" (KDCs) don't need to be provided; each AD DC is a Kerberos KDC, but Kerberos will find them through DNS SRV records.
The third prompt conflates Kpasswd servers (every AD DC accepts password change requests) and Kadmin servers (which AD does not have at all; all administration is done through LDAP). I think you still don't need to enter anything here, as DNS SRV records will provide that information, but I don't quite remember whether that works by default in AD. If necessary you can enter the name of one of your AD DCs.

But as mentioned, this is only enough for outbound access; it just sets defaults for kinit. To set up a full AD join so that AD users could log in to your server through the "regular" login methods, you really need to use either Samba/winbindd (net join) or SSSD (realm join).
(On the other hand: You don't need an AD join if the goal is only to set up a webapp that accepts Kerberos authentication; it's enough to have an AD admin create a "service" user account and set SPNs.)

When I ran the "realm join -U username@xyz.edu "ad.xyz.edu" ask for the password as I am not admin at the ad.xyz.edu level but I am admin at med.abc.edu level

You need the permissions to create a computer account in AD. This doesn't necessarily need AD admin rights – it might be enough to be an Account Operator or have a custom delegation, and then you should be able to use --computer-ou= or ask another AD admin to pre-create a computer account for you.
This is practically the same as joining a Windows system, so ask your AD admins.
If a computer account has been created, you can do the realm join without specifying a username; I think you use --no-password in that situation. (The computer account needs to be passwordless, i.e. freshly created or reset.)

Thanks You for clearing my confusion
